# Motor Power Increases towards Max Speed - Why?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

I cannot find any literature on the reason for this curve I have in my v/f profile of a BLDC motor.

I have taken measurements of the power in (from my DC power supply), the RPM and the supply voltage. I have used this to calculate the torque.

It is clear from this picture that we have a (nearly) constant torque region. After this, the power and torque decreases. I understand this to be as a result of the back EMF decreasing at the higher RPMs. I've heard the word "power developed" a few times.

[image: measurements and calculations]

The motor is rated for 24V and 4000RPM. I am driving it with 12V and you can see it gets up to 4000 RPM.

What I don't understand is why the power increases at the very end. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the kick up at the end is due to the powersupply counteracting the backEMF. The Vemf goes above 12V when the current begins to kick back up.

This article is the only graph I've seen that shows what's going on with my current. It is due to the fact that I don't have a load on the motor.

https://www.embedded.com/implementing-embedded-speed-control-for-brushless-dc-motors-part-5/

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a DC motor is brushless means it has some internal commutation *and control* mechanism. This "smart controller" could be trying to compensate for the voltage change, and the torque change likely is a *result of that internal controller's programming*. One cannot take into account back-EMF while the controller is manipulating phase timing and current draw.

Try that experiment with a *brush commutated* DC motor to get more easily understood results.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am programming the controller itself in an open loop v/f function, so the voltage doesn't change after 2250 RPM, which you can see in the top graph is when the UQ reference flattens.

The system is open loop so there is no feedback compensation happening, there is just an increase in the current drawn by the motor suddenly towards the top. What doesn't make sense is why the power doesn't flat line after the v/f curve reaches it's max and the torque decreases. I don't understand why the torque AND power decrease.